# Meteor 1.6 Meteor.userId() a reliable way of checking users?

Tags: meteor, react-router-v4

I'm currently working on a administration for a site, and I was wondering what's the best way to check if user is logged in and render the routes to give access to it.

From meteor's documentation I can see: https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-userId

Which is a quite a convenient way, but I'm wondering if it is secure enough to render administration routes on the client side.

Here's an example to what I would like to do :

```
const checkFunction=()=>{
    if(Meteor.isClient){
        return Meteor.userId();
    }
}
const PrivateRoute = ({ layout, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
     checkFunction() ? (
        React.createElement( layout, props, React.createElement(component, props))
    ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Eventhough I make sure that every modifications on the database are also checked server side, I don't want to give an insecure access to my administration.

Comment: You cannot count on anything on the client side, as the client can manipulate anything there. Every piece of sensitive data or action that concerns the client need to be checked on the server. While you may route to the administrative view on the client, the data that populates it needs to come from a source that checks the user's identity before sending it to the client.

Comment: I also think this is clearly stated in the [Meteor Security Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html), especially the last section [checklist](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#checklist) has this pointed out: `8.Secure the data, not the UI - redirecting away from a client-side route does nothing for security, it’s just a nice UX feature.`

Comment: Thx for your answers, I was aware of that, but I was wondering what's the best way then to check user's identity before rendering routes.